# How to change Font type in a text area using a combobox

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7, jcombobox, jtextarea

I am doing a simple text editor and have a combo box filled with the font names. However I can't manage to make the program change the font of the text area when a new font is selected form the combo box. I was using this line of code to try and make it work.

```
txtArea.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 16));
```

I need to replace "Serif" with some kind of variable to change from the font from the selected font type from the combo box.

All help will be really appreciated.

Comment: what framework ? java fx or awt ?

Answer (score 1):

OK, if your combo box is filled with available font names, you can try like this:

```
    fontComboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                txtArea.setFont(new Font((String) fontComboBox.getSelectedItem(), Font.ITALIC, 16));
            }
        }
    });
```